# ReSharper go to, open result in current window

Tags: resharper

I'm using ReSharper with VSVim and I have some shortcuts setup to navigate around using the various Go To X features, but I find them hard to fit into a split based workflow because instead of opening in the currently active split (like I am used to from vim) they always open in a new window.

I've looked at the documentation and I can't find any mention of this, but is it possible to change their behavior to always replace the currently active split with the file I'm navigating to?

Comment: Please, clarify that you mean by X in your equation. Does visual studio's navigation work for you as you expect?

Comment: By X I mean "Go to File", "Go to String", "Go to Declaration". I don't think VS navigation works like I want either, but I only use VS navigation to open files via the solution explorer. I think the main issue stems from when using vim I rarely use tabs, I use many buffers instead. But tabs are standard in VS.

Comment: I'm afraid that visual studio does not suit your need because buffer in Visual Studio is bound to tab. There is no abstraction layer between view and document like it is implemented in VIM.